# Excel 2011 conditional formatting, problems w/ adding deleting rows

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a standard form I use that requires an row to be highlighted one of 7 colors when a condition is met in a cell in that row.  The form varies wildly in length.  Currently, I am using conditional formatting for this behavior.  However, every time I delete or add rows, it breaks apart the conditional formatting into 2 pieces.  This causes some issues and "managing the rules" is pretty time consuming.  One thought I had would be to keep the formatting on another sheet in the workbook that I do not edit, and then applying it at the end, if that is possible.  Has anyone found a work around for this?  Is this kind of entire row formatting with color based on one cell possible in a way that does not require conditional formatting?

Comment: What do you have to update to make the conditional format work?  Is it updating certain cells?

Comment: Try applying the conditial formatting to the entire spreadsheet.